# Are all the objects in C++ mutable if not stated otherwise?

Tags: c++11, immutability

Is every object in C++  mutable if not stated otherwise?

In Python and Javascript I can't change strings, tuple, unicodes. I was wondering if there is something in C++ that is immutable or every object is mutable and I have to use `const` type qualifier to make it immutable.

Comment: what do you mean with "by default"?

Comment: That all the objects in C++ are mutable if not stated differently.

Comment: Yes they are.
Note this is not the same as the "mutable" keyword.

Comment: The question in the question body is a different question from the question in the title?

Comment: @immibis it was only to add a litle bit of contest

Comment: String literals are not mutable - you must not write to them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Immutability has been well-understood for some time. Python, Java, and C++ have different memory models that make direct comparisons difficult. The author of the [article you originally cited](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/the-need-for-immutability/231000092) ([permalink](https://web.archive.org/web/20190721111912/https://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/the-need-for-immutability/231000092)) doesn't seem to know C++.

As in Python, Java, and most multi-paradigm languages, C and C++ allow mutability by default. This is what programmers usually want: if I have an `String x` variable, I want to be able to assign a new value `x = "foo"`.

The const-system in C and C++ allows a great deal of nuanced immutability that is lacking in Python, Java, and even Scala. If a C++ function takes a `const std::string&` or a `const char*`, it promises (and the compiler ensures, to some degree), that this function will not (cannot!) change the contents of that string. Given a const object, we can only invoke methods of that object that are also marked as const. If a C++ class only has public members which are `const`, then the object is effectively immutable.

However, this is sometimes confusing as in C and C++ objects are memory locations, and variables are names for memory locations. In contrast, variables in Python and Java are names for pointers to objects. In a language with reference semantics, `x = y` means “make x point to the same object as y”. Since we are only copying pointers, this is possible with immutable objects. In a language with value semantics like C++, it means “update the contents of `x` with the contents of `y`”. Therefore, if reassignment of a variable is desired in C or C++, the variable may not have a const type. To do this with immutable objects, we would have to use a pointer explicitly.

That Java and Python use immutable string objects is a fundamental design decision, but it is not directly connected to the benefits of immutability in a multithreading environment. One reason is that string literals in the source code can be pooled which reduces the number of objects. This is possible in C/C++ as well. In C++ the literal `"foo"` has type `const char[4]` (the 4th char is the terminating `'\0'`). Another reason is that entries in sets and keys in dicts/maps must not be changed. Since strings are used pervasively as dict keys (most Python objects are a dict), immutability removes a common source of errors. In Java, another reason for immutable strings is the Java security model. All of these reasons are entirely unrelated to multithreading.

If Java were built with immutability in mind, the language would have looked very differently. While it is closely inspired by C++, the designers tried hard to create a much simpler language, getting rid of const is one such step. The equivalent Java thing to a C++ const reference is an adapter or decorator that implements any mutating methods as `throws new NotImplementedException()`, and forwards non-mutating method calls to the actual collection. The fact that the java.util collection interfaces all imply mutability is a clear sign they didn't strive for an immutability-first language.

The solution Java put forward to solve concurrency problems wasn't immutability, but pervasive locking. Every single object contains a mutex that may be used for `synchronized` blocks or entire methods. As it turns out, that is not good for performance, does not scale very well, and is quite error prone – you still have to deal with mutable global state.

Comment: *This is what programmers usually want* => that's quite the controversial claim. My experience is actually the opposite: most local variables are immutable, with the occasionally mutable one. Languages such as Rust (where mutability requires a `mut` keyword, and where unnecessary mutability is flagged by the compiler) tend to support my hypothesis: in Rust, you have much more `let` bindings than you have `let mut` ones.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: That's partially because `for x in 1..10` doesn't use `let mut` to define the loop variable, but obviously it requires some mutability (at loop level only, not inside the loop body).

Comment: @MSalters: Of course, but C++ has range-for syntax too :)

Comment: @MSalters I would characterise that as binding 10 variables called x with 10 values, not mutating one

Comment: I'd say the programmers' opinion on *immutable* is a trend that is catching on, therefore its percentage is changing (in favor) over time. Remember that not every CS undergrad program properly equips its students to think in immutability. Even those that teach functional programming languages do not always embrace immutability (remember you can have mutability, and you can certainly design in mutable thinking), and basically do not highlight immutability as a desirable trait except where race conditions are a concern.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I agree that immutability is nice, but in C++ it's simply not always an option, or at least excessively awkward. E.g. initialising a const variable in multiple steps requires us to do that in a separate function where that object isn't yet const. At least C++11 let's us use immediately-invoked lambdas like `const T o = [&]{T o; o.init(...); return o;}();` … yay for APIs that weren't designed with immutability in mind.

Answer (score 11):

Almost. The language itself treats everything as mutable unless you use `const`, *but* it's still possible to build immutable objects without telling the compiler they're immutable, by simply not providing a way to mutate them.

For example, take this class:

```
class MyClass {
    int value;
public:

    MyClass(int v) : value(v) {}
    int getValue() {return value;}

    MyClass &operator=(const MyClass &other) = delete;
};
```

Instances of `MyClass` are immutable, because there's no way to mutate them - but nowhere in the code is it actually *stated* they are immutable. (This is the same way that instances of Java's `String` class are immutable)

Comment: (I'm getting rusty) Does `delete`ing the copy-assignment operator here also ensure one cannot assign from an rvalue reference via the move-assignment op?

Comment: And does destroying the object with an explicit destructor call and then re-creating it with placement new count as "mutating"?

Comment: @underscore_d It counts as user-defining the operator for the purposes of not implicitly adding a move assignment, yes

Comment: I wonder whether a mechanism to let the compiler know that objects of a certain class are always immutable could lead to better optimization. For example it would be unnecessary to refresh cashed objects. In this particular example (and generally in classes following this pattern) it would probably help to declare `value` const, and to declare `getValue()` a const function.

Comment: @PeterGreen No, that counts as destroying the object and creating a new one.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is one exception: Lambdas and by extension the objects they capture are immutable by default:

```
int i = 0;

[i]{//capturing the value i
    i++; //does not compile, i is const
};

[i]() mutable{ //make the lambda mutable
    i++; //compiles fine
};
```

So instead of adding `const` to make it immutable you add `mutable` to make it not `const`.

Comment: Only capturing lambdas are immutable by default since C++20, non capturing lambdas have defaulted assignment in C++20

Comment: The values lambdas capture are just copies of the original and are mutable.  Function parameters are also just copies of the original and are mutable.  It's just that you can't do anything with the copy.

Comment: "The values lambdas capture are just copies of the original and are mutable."
[The standard disagrees](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#closure-5.sentence-1):
"The function call operator or operator template is declared const ([class.mfct.non.static]) if and only if the lambda-expression's parameter-declaration-clause is not followed by mutable and the lambda-declarator does not contain an explicit object parameter."

Comment: I guess you could argue that `i` is not `const` and that only the `operator()` is `const` which then affects `i`. So more specifically not the lambda or its members are `const` by default but the `operator()`.